# Saving created .kea files

Tags: python, gdal, jupyter-notebook

I have the following script that converts a list of .tiff files in the working folder to .kea files using gdal_translate.
When I run the script in the command line it works fine and creates the .kea files.
However when I try to run it on a Jupyter Notebook it does not seems to work.
Is something missing from the code?

```
import os.path
import sys

def replaceGTIFF_kea(inputtext):
outputtext = ""    
for w in inputtext:
    w = w.replace("GEOTIFF","KEA")
    w = w.replace(".TIF",".kea")
    # this line should be unnecessary since Landsat MTL files use capital letters       
    # but just in case you have one that doesn't
    w = w.replace(".tif",".kea")
    outputtext += w
    return outputtext

# find all *.TIF files and *MTL.txt files in the current directory
 directory = os.getcwd()
 dirFileList = os.listdir(directory)
# print dirFileList
 tifFileList = [f for f in dirFileList if ((f[-4:]=='.TIF')or(f[-4:]=='.tif'))]
 MTLFileList = [f for f in dirFileList if (f[-7:]=='MTL.txt')]

#output format (GDAL code)
outFormat = 'KEA'

# run gdal_translate on all TIFs to convert to KEA
for t in tifFileList:
    gdaltranscmd = "gdal_translate -of "+outFormat+" "+t+" "+t[:-4]+".kea"
    print (gdaltranscmd)
    os.system(gdaltranscmd)

# create a new header file referring to .kea files rather than .TIF
for m in MTLFileList:
    inputtext = file(m).readlines()
    outputtext = replaceGTIFF_kea(inputtext)
    outputfilebase = m[:-4]
    outputfile = outputfilebase + "_kea.txt"
    out = file(outputfile,"w")
    out.write(outputtext)
    out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had the different version of Gdal installed and that's why it did not work.